# How to display the total number of changes in Vim’s diff mode?

Tags: vim, diff

When diffing two files in Vim, is it possible to display the total number of changes? I suppose, this is equivalent to counting the number of folds, but I don’t know how to do that either.

Ideally, I would like a message which says something like “*Change 1 of 12*”, which would update as I cycle through the changes with `]c`.

I’m having great success converting some members of my office to the wonders of Vim, but Vimdiff is a consistent bugbear.

Comment: Do you mean the number of *hunks* (or *changes* as `vim` calls them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly more refined solution. It uses the same technique as my previous answer to count the diffs, but it stores the first line of each hunk in a list asigned to a global variable `g:diff_hunks`. Then the number of hunks below the cursor can be found by finding the position of the line number in the list. Also notice that I set `nocursorbind` and `noscrollbind` and reset them at the end to ensure we don't break mouse scrolling in the diff windows.

```
function! UpdateDiffHunks()
    setlocal nocursorbind
    setlocal noscrollbind
    let winview = winsaveview() 
    let pos = getpos(".")
    sil exe 'normal! gg'
    let moved = 1
    let hunks = []
    while moved
        let startl = line(".")
        keepjumps sil exe 'normal! ]c'
        let moved = line(".") - startl
        if moved
            call add(hunks,line("."))
        endif
    endwhile
    call winrestview(winview)
    call setpos(".",pos)
    setlocal cursorbind
    setlocal scrollbind
    let g:diff_hunks = hunks
endfunction
```

The function `UpdateDiffHunks()` should be updated whenever a diff buffer is modified, but I find it sufficient to map it to `CursorMoved` and `BufEnter`.

```
function! DiffCount()
    if !exists("g:diff_hunks") 
        call UpdateDiffHunks()
    endif
    let n_hunks = 0
    let curline = line(".")
    for hunkline in g:diff_hunks
        if curline < hunkline
            break
        endif
        let n_hunks += 1
    endfor
    return n_hunks . '/' . len(g:diff_hunks)
endfunction
```

The output of `DiffCount()` can be used in the statusline, or tied to a command.

Comment: Thanks, it it very useful, but I only successfully made it work in vim/nvim when manually execute like `:echo DiffCount()` to show the result such as `1/10` in statusline, how can I make it displayed automatically in status line like you said `CursorMoved`. I used `autocmd CursorMoved, BufEnter * :echo DiffCount()`, but it always displays `0/0`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here's the best I could come up with myself. This function starts at the top of the current buffer and using the `]c` motion it moves through the changes until `]c` no longer has an effect. It returns the number of changes (or `0` if the cursor if it is not a diff buffer).

```
function! CountDiffs()
    let winview = winsaveview() 
    let num_diffs = 0
    if &diff
        let pos = getpos(".")
        keepj sil exe 'normal! G'
        let lnum = 1
        let moved = 1
        while moved
            let startl = line(".")
            keepj sil exe 'normal! [c'
            let moved = line(".") - startl
            if moved
                let num_diffs+=1
            endif
        endwhile
        call winrestview(winview)
        call setpos(".",pos)
    endif
    return num_diffs
endfunction
```

It seems to work okay, and isn't a noticeable performance hit when included in my statusline.

As for finding the "number" of the current change, here is a function that uses the backward `[c` motion to count the number of changes before the position of the cursor. The returned value isn't quite right... I think maybe it should only return a number if the cursor is "within" the changed text, rather than after the first line of the change.

```
function! CurrentDiff()
    if &diff
        let num_diff = 0
        let winview = winsaveview() 
        let pos = getpos(".")
        let moved = 1
        while moved
            let startl = line(".")
            keepj sil exe 'normal! [c'
            let moved = line(".") - startl
            if moved
                let num_diff+=1
            endif
        endwhile
        call winrestview(winview)
        call setpos(".",pos)
        return num_diff
    endif
endfunction
```

Again, it seems to behave itself in my statusline and doesn't affect the movement of the cursor. The numbers update properly as changes are copied too/from the buffer.

Once the problems have been ironed out I might consider uploading this as a plugin on the Vim website.